# Would a Mars flyby be possible on a transfer orbit from Saturn's moon of Titan to Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacecraft, orbital-maneuver, hohmann-transfer

So, I am trying to calculate whether a transfer burn from Saturn's moon of Titan to Earth would involve a Mars flyby, assuming I have the burn start on 2 March, 2025 and arrival on 19 March, 2031. This is all done via calculations on a MS Excel calculator for Hohmann Transfer Launch Windows, so take the specific dates with a grain of salt. During that timeframe, could a spacecraft on a Hohmann Transfer Orbit heading for Earth be able to flyby Mars? Or not really?

Comment: Just calculate where Mars will be, when your Hohmann ellipse crosses the Mars orbit...

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape. I would, but I have NO IDEA of how to do it manually. At all.......

Comment: @FutureHistorian There are various tools (with varying degrees of fidelity and ease-of-use) you can use to play with this idea.  There's STK (a professional tool used broadly across the industry), NASA's GMAT (an open source mission design tool), Orbiter (a freeware orbital mechanics simulator/game) with the TransX plugin (which is meant to design complex interplanetary trajectories), and others, I'm sure.  They all have learning curves of various degrees, but they can get you started.

Comment: @Tristan. Any of them that do NOT necessarily mean starting on Earth? I will explain this elsewhere. :/

Comment: @FutureHistorian Sure, any of those that I mentioned do *NOT* require you to start on earth. You can set up your initial situation as you see fit. (edited to add an important word I accidentally left out in the last comment ;-) )